# modulus operations on long long in c++

Tags: c++, primes, prime-factoring

I am working on prime factorization on large numbers (mainly, [project 3 @ project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=3).  I need to use the modulus on numbers declared as long long.  Everytime I try to modulus that gigantic number I get a floating point exception.  Any help would be profusely appreciated.  Thanks.

I have run this through gdb and see what's happening.  Below is my code.  It's very rough logic at this point.  **Please do not give me the answer to the problem**.  I will gladly accept help on making this better, just please do not give me the straight up answer.  Thanks :)

```
long factor(long number) {
  string br = "\n\r";
  long x = 0;
  /*this modulus variable is an attempt
  to move the answer into a long long container
  to see if that solves my floating point exception,
  it didn't*/
  long long modulus;

  while(x <= number) {
    modulus = number % x;
    if(modulus == 0) {
      cout << number/x << br;
      return factor(number/x);
    }//if number % x
    else {
      return x;
    }//else
    x++;
  }//while

}//factor
```

Comment: What compiler? What platform?

Comment: @David: Why does it matter? Anything mod 0 will give an exception for all compilers I have worked with.

Comment: @Andrew Well, that's certainly a compelling argument!!

Comment: If `number` isn't divisible by `2`, then neither is `number/x`.  Testing all the small primes all over again for each recursion level isn't efficient.

Comment: ...*speechless* can't believe I didn't see that.  And I'm the world's biggest idiot.  And just cause you asked it is g++ (gcc) on ubuntu natty narwhal.

Comment: x++ will never get executed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't try to mod by 0, it's undefined! Doing so will result in a divide-by-zero error.

```
long x = 0;
modulus = number % x; // x is 0 here and thus not valid
```

To expand a bit on my answer, per [Wikipedia's article on Modulo Operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

> *a* modulo 0 is undefined in the majority of systems, although some do define it to be a.

Comment: Thanks.  I can't believe I didn't see that, oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Start with

```
long x = 1 ;
```

to avoid a division by zero.